# grep [a-z] producing 1 character

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to grep for a specific string with two identifiable characters.. example of this is

```
grep -rhIo '[a-zA-z]@[a-zA-z]\.com]
```

input file example:

```
name:phone:example@example.com
```

which should theoretically output:

```
example@example.com
```

but it will only output

```
e@e
```

so some how I need to indicate that a-z can be unlimited length and not just one char

Comment: The expression `[a-zA-Z]` _is_ a pattern which will match exactly one character.  If you want zero or more of those, use `[a-zA-z]*`].  `+` will, in an extended regex, match on _one_ or more.  So you probably want to use for your pattern: `[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-z.-]+\.[a-z]+`.

Comment: I assume you left off the trailing single quote by accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even use `grep` in the example you posted, it's simple enough to be handled by `cut`:

```
$ echo name:phone:example@example.com | rev | cut -d: -f1 | rev
example@example.com
```

***EDIT*:**

But if you want `grep` it would be something like this:

```
$ echo name:phone:example@example.com | grep -oE '[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com'
example@example.com
```

Note that `+` is used which stands `one or more instances` of the previous character in regular expressions and that `-E` has to be used with grep for that to work:

```
-E, --extended-regexp

      Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).
      (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the information, it solved the problem that was occurring :)!

Comment: Why do you use `rev`? Why not just `cut` the third field?

Comment: In the case the were more fields - with `rev` we'll always get the last one.